# Javascript check if input is a percentage

Tags: javascript

Just wondering if anyone can let me know how I can check if input from a website is a percentage? i.e. 50%. So if this is true I can use another prompt telling them that it must be a percentage and ask them to re-enter.

Here is my Javascript code:

```
function changeprogressclient() {
    var howmuch = prompt("Please enter a custom percentage", "50%");
    document.getElementById('progbar').style.width = howmuch;
    $("#progressnumber").html(howmuch);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test the *String* has a valid pattern using *RegExp*

```
if (/^\d+(\.\d+)?%$/.test(howmuch)) {
    // pass
} else {
    // fail
}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo on Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/3X1bCyNAIBl8N4YL)

Comment: Won't allow `.5%` but I suspect we can forgive that :-) Also wouldn't allow `7.%` but that would be far less common.

Comment: Should probably allow them to not type the percent symbol... if I'm using the website it seems superfluous and annoying to have typed 50 into the textbox just to get an error telling me that `50` is not a percent... Although admittedly that's more a problem for the OP

Answer (score 2):

I found a better solution that Paul's answer:

```regex
^(\d+|(\.\d+))(\.\d+)?%$
```

```js
if (/^(\d+|(\.\d+))(\.\d+)?%$/.test(howmuch)) {
  // String is a percentage
}
```

it matches:

50%

50.5%

0.5%

.5%